# Deserialize a JSON string to a class that wrapps a generic class

Tags: java, generics, gson

First some context.

I have this wrapper class:

```java
public class ResponseEntity<T> {
    private String code;
    private String message;
    private T data;

    public ResponseEntity(String code, String message, T data) {
        this.code = code;
        this.message = message;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public ResponseEntity(String code, String message) {
        this.code = code;
        this.message = message;
        this.data = null;
    }

  ...getters...
}
```

Then I have the class I use inside:

```java
public class Foo {
    private String name;
    private String age;

    public Foo(String name, String age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    ...getters...
}
```

Im using AWS Lambda so ResponseEntity is serialized in a `body` field inside an AWS Lambda response class:
`some-lambda-handler-class.java`

```java
public APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent handleRequest(String name, String age) {
  Foo foo = new Foo(name, age);
  ResponseEntity<Foo> fooResponse = new ResponseEntity("code", "msg", foo);
  String body = gson.toJson(fooResponse);
  APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent response = new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent();
  response.setBody(body);
  return response;
}
```

The problem is when I test my handler class:
`some-lambda-handler-class-test.java`

```java
@Test
public void test() {
    APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent response = myHandler.handleRequest("foo", "bar");
    ResponseEntity<Foo> fooResponse = gson.fromJson(response.getBody(), ResponseEntity.class);

    assertThat(fooResponse.getCode(), is("code")); // This assert is Ok
    assertThat(fooResponse.getMessage(), is("msg")); // This assert is Ok
    assertThat(fooResponse.getData().getName(), is("foo")); // this throws an error 
// Error is: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to class Foo (com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap and Foo are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    assertThat(fooResponse.getData().getAge(), is("bar"));
}
```

What I understand from this error is that somehow I have to tell gson that the class I want to deserialize from the json is a `ResponseEntity<Foo>.class` so insetead of using a `LinkedTreeMap` as the `data` field, use `Foo`.

But I don't know how to do it. Because if I do:

```java
ResponseEntity<Foo> fooResponse = gson.fromJson(response.getBody(), ResponseEntity<Foo>.class);
// The "ResponseEntity<Foo>.class" part shows an error ("Cannot select from parameterized type")
```

So the question is,

**how do I tell Gson to deserialize the JSON string to a `ResponseEntity<Foo>` class?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Class` does not retain type parameterization, thus does not really fit `gson.fromJson(..., type)`. Gson makes use of `ParameterizedType`, and you have at least three options: 1) create your own implementation (for better understanding of Java types); 2) subclass `TypeToken` to take type from (creates additional classes but compile-time safe); 3) use `TypeToken.getParameterized` (creates no additional classes, but not compile-time safe).

Comment: Thanks @fluffy for your response. Could you provide an example on the option that you think is better for testing purposes?

Comment: I would take the option no. 2 (despite it may create multiple `...$1.class`, `...$2.class` etc by default), and put all type tokens as `public static final TypeToken<...> ...TypeToken = ...` in a dedicated class shared in production and test code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use

```
gson.fromJson(response.getBody(), new TypeToken<ResponseEntity<Foo>>() {}.getType());
```

since you use a wrapped class

```
ResponseEntity<Foo>.class
```

is not possible, since `.class` ignores <> parms

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this solution